# WCF binding with worker role Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, binding

I am using VSTS 2010 + C# + .Net 4.0. I am trying to host WCF in Windows Azure. When executing the following statement in the worker role, there is the following binding not found error. Here I am doing manual configuration of wcf.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AzureWcfService));
```

I am getting error as:

> Configuration binding extension
>   'system.serviceModel/bindings/NetTcpBinding' could not be found.
>   Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is
>   spelled correctly.

My ServiceDefinition.csdef file is as follows

```
<Endpoints>

  <InputEndpoint name="port" protocol="tcp" port="9001" />
  <InputEndpoint name="mexport" protocol="tcp" port="8001" />
</Endpoints>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your app.config, and it's likely that you want to use the `netTcpRelayBinding`, which is Azure's load-balancing-friendly binding:

```
<extensions>

  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="connectionStatusBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="serviceRegistrySettings" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="httpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="httpsRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="onewayRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="webHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netEventRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
```